# for loop with 2 iterators and 2 ranges

Tags: python, loops, iterator

I am a newbie of Python and dealing with a prime generator. The algorithm i wanna use is [Sieve of Atkin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Atkin).

At this moment, I am trying to follow the pseudo code of the algorithm as my practice. However, I have faced a problem and I can't find any reference about it. (Maybe I am not good at searching...). In the pseudo code, `for (x, y) in [1, √limit] × [1, √limit]:...` makes me confused. I know what it means but don't know how to translate this code into Python code.

Sorry if my question is not appropriate, and thanks for the help. :)

Below is a part of my code.

```
itx = iter(range(1, int(limit**0.5)))
ity = iter(range(1, int(limit**0.5)))
for x, y in zip(itx, ity):
    n = 4*(x**2)+(y**2)
    if n <= limit and (n%12 == 1 or n%12 == 5):
        sieve[n] = not sieve[n]

    n = 3*(x**2)+(y**2)
    if n <= limit and n%12 == 7:
        sieve[n] = not sieve[n]

    n = 3*(x**2)-(y**2)
    if x > y and n <= limit and n%12 == 11:
        sieve[n] = not sieve[n]

    itx.next()
    ity.next()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`for (x, y) in [1, √limit] × [1, √limit]` should be translated to a product:

```
for x in itx:
    for y in ity:
```

or using [`itertools.product()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
from itertools import product

for x, y in product(itx, ity):
```

Note that you do **not** need to call `.next()` on the iterators! Remove the `itx.next()` and `ity.next()` lines, unless you *mean* to skip generated values. The `for` construct advances the iterators for you.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of `zip(itx, ity)`, you need to use `itertools.product(itx, ity)`.

`zip` iterates over two iterators in parallel (operation known as [convolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution_%28computer_science%29)), yielding pairs of matching items and ending iteration when the shortest iterator is exhausted. `itertools.product` iterates over the [*Cartesian product*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) of the two iterators, yielding pairs of all combinations of items from one and the other set. The latter is what the `×` operator refers to.

As Martijn Pieters pointed out, manually calling `.next()` on the iterators is incorrect, since `for` advances them itself, and doing it yourself you end up only processing every second item of the iterable. Also, `iter(range(...))` is unnecessary — simply use `xrange` (or `range` in Python 3).